# Backup / Restore fails with Odoo / OpenERP

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, odoo

Having an issue with Odoo 9 enterprise:
When using the database manager, this error appears when backing up:

```
Database backup error: Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmptv_tLH/dump.sql', u'mydb') error 1
```

Here is the output from Odoos log:

```
2016-04-18 14:08:45,067 28275 INFO mydb openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_autovacuum: GC'd 1 user log entries

2016-04-18 14:08:51,514 28275 INFO mydb openerp.service.db: DUMP DB: mydb format zip

2016-04-18 14:08:51,619 28275 ERROR mydb openerp.addons.web.controllers.main: Database.backup

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 721, in backup

dump_stream = openerp.service.db.dump_db(name, None, backup_format)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/db.py", line 180, in dump_db

openerp.tools.exec_pg_command(*cmd)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/misc.py", line 121, in exec_pg_command

raise Exception('Postgres subprocess %s error %s' % (args2, rc))

Exception: Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmptv_tLH/dump.sql', u'mydb') error 1
```

- Nothing appears in postgres log.  Creating a database works fine, as
  does deleting.
- I do not have GIS installed.
- This is a fresh install.
- I can run the pg_dump from my commandline as the same user    and it
  works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Amazon RDS defaults to postgres 9.4.7. When I spun up a new instance with 9.3.5, I got segmentation faults. Upgrading to 9.3.6 and everything works fine.